# How to generate my menu in primary location in wordpress php site

Tags: php, wordpress, function

to avoid installing my menu in each pages (sidebar.php, index.php, category.php, etc.), i create a template part (a php.file) for my menu, for example :

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying menu in Twenty Eleven Child Theme
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage My Twenty_Eleven Child Theme
 * @since My Twenty Eleven Child Theme 1.0
 */
?>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://www.mylink1.com/">home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.mylink2.com/">about</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.mylink3.com/">contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then i install the `<?php get_menu(); ?>` after the `<div id="primary">` in each page where i want to show the menu...

**I guess i must also make some codes in the function.php (register the menu), how should i do ???
What else should i do still ?**

Please note that i do not know much about php !

Thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: You want to create the function to generate your menu in the theme functions file, then just call the function as you said above **after <div id="primary">** . With WP menus you can give it various options the best thing I can suggest it to have a look [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) The example code will work nicely for your basic menu. Hope this helps??

Comment: Thanks for your answer... however, i do not want to use the classical menu option of WP, i created a php template for it (see it above). 
Simply i would like to avoid writting all the codes of the menu in each page file, i would like to call my menu only with get_menu... (like get_sidebar, get_footer, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would push my answer out of the comments:

```
function get_menu(){
    $menu = "<div class='menu'><ul><li><a href='/link'>Link</a></li></ul></div>";
    return $menu;
}
```

Then on the page:

```
<?php $get_menu = get_menu(); echo $get_menu; ?>
```

Unless you wanted to register your `get_menu` as a global variable in that case you would just need to `<?php echo get_menu(); ?>`

Comment: Th echo seems ok but i have questions about it : 1) my menu list is quiet long with 18 images and links, isn't it too heavy for the functions file ? 2) about your second and third codes, you mean that i must use the third one `<?php echo get_menu(); ?>` instead of the second one ? I will try and i come back later and thanks a lot !